# how lazy is DeltaTable.toDF (Spark and delta.io)?

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

Suppose you do something like

```scala
import io.delta.tables._

val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "...")

deltaTable.updateExpr(
  "column_name = value",
  Map("updated_column" -> "'new_value'")

val df = deltaTable.toDF
```

Will `df` re-read the underlying Delta table contents on demand whenever accessed (e.g., `df.count()`), post-update?  Such that `deltaTable.toDF` is effectively equivalent to `spark.read.format("delta").load(path)`?

Or will it re-apply the series of updates whenever `df` is accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use `.toDF()` on a `DeltaTable` in Apache Spark, you're getting the most current snapshot of the table's data at the moment you execute your code. This is due to [the ways that the DeltaTable object is created, and the way that .toDF is executed](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/v3.0.0/spark/src/main/scala/io/delta/tables/DeltaTable.scala#L716), which does not pin to a particular version. So, when you update a DeltaTable and then read it with `deltaTable.toDF()`, Spark fetches the updated data at that moment.

We can override this behavior with some use of the time travel API, see **Pinned reads** below.

**Pinned reads**

Let's say you want to consistently read from the same version of a Delta table more than one time, even if the table gets updated in the meantime. You can 'pin' the table to a specific version like this:

```
// Optional: Get the latest version of the table at the start of your session.
val latestHistRow = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, tablePath)
                              .history() // Retrieve table history
                              .limit(1)  // Get the latest version
                              .collect() // Eagerly evaluate to get the version info
                              .apply(0)  // Pull the only Row out

val pinnedVersion = latestHistRow.getLong(latestHistRow.fieldIndex("version"))

// Use this version for reading the table
val df = spark.read
              .format("delta")
              .option("versionAsOf", pinnedVersion) // "time travel"
              .load(tablePath)
```

This way, df will always represent the data of the Delta table at pinnedVersion, even if newer versions are available.

And please remember that Delta Lake has [data retention settings](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#data-retention) that determine how long old versions are kept, so the efficacy of this approach depends on those settings.

Comment: Interesting.  I think the answer to my specific question was all in the first sentence - I think you're saying that `DeltaTable.toDF` is equivalent to `spark.read.format("delta")`, which will read the latest state from delta files, unless you override the version ID as you demonstrate.

Comment: Correct. I had the same question you did, but in a slightly different context - it was used for the situation I wrote about at the bottom. Then I did some quick testing to confirm and shared here!